# Changing color of oval in word docx using openxml

Tags: c#-4.0, openxml-sdk

I have a template document that contains an Oval.  I am able to access the oval with the following code and while debugging I see the value of the FillColor changing, but when the word docx is opened, the oval is the original color.

I am using this code as a test.  The color change will be dynamic based on application values. Trying to get the correct format for the FillColor string.

more info - added changing some text in the oval (using same code that changes header in body) and that didn't save either.

```
public ActionResult ....
{
.... other code newpath = copy of original  word Template as you suggested with one Header to replace and Oval
        WordUpdateDocxProfile(pptvm, newpath, replacethem, colwidths, 4, 0);
        //download file and then delete
        DownloadandDelete(newpath);
        Return View();

} 



private void WordUpdateDocxProfile(PerfProfileTotalsViewModel m, string newpath, List<MatrixReplaceViewModel> replacethem, List<int> colwidths, int textcols, int numcols)
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(newpath, true))
            {
                var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                var paras = body.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>();
                WordReplaceItems(paras, replacethem);
                IEnumerable<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Oval> shapes = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Oval>();
                foreach( var oo in shapes)
                {
                   oo.FillColor= "#c5e0b3 [1305]";
                    IEnumerable<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph> ps = oo.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>();
                    List<MatrixReplaceViewModel> replacerv = new List<MatrixReplaceViewModel>();
                    replacerv.Add(new MatrixReplaceViewModel { replacewith = "RV", toreplace = "RS" });
                    replacerv.Add(new MatrixReplaceViewModel { replacewith = "2.7", toreplace = "Val" });
                    replacerv.Add(new MatrixReplaceViewModel { replacewith = "Valuesss", toreplace = "Score" });
                    WordReplaceItems(ps, replacerv);


}
            }
        }
 private void WordReplaceItems(IEnumerable<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph> paras, List<MatrixReplaceViewModel> replacethem)
        {
            foreach (var para in paras)
            {
                foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
                {
                    foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>())
                    {
                        foreach (var replace in replacethem)
                        {
                            if (text.Text.Contains(replace.toreplace))
                            {
                                text.Text = text.Text.Replace(replace.toreplace, replace.replacewith);
                                break;  //leave if we found and replaced in this text element within the run
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

 private void DownloadandDelete(string path)
        {
            //download file and then delete
            System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
                Response.End();
            }
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
        }
```

At the end of the using WordprocessingDocument doc = ... in WordUpdateDocxProfile, the value when drilling down to the oval.FillColor = "#c5e0b3 [1305]".  I have stopped the code before going to DownloadandDelete(newpath) and opened the word document in Open XML SDK Productivity Tool.  Header text is changed, but Oval FillColor is not.

This is from Open XML SDK Productivity Tool

> Oval oval1 = new Oval(){ Id = "Oval 1", Style =
>   "position:absolute;left:0;text-align:left;margin-left:0;margin-top:-.05pt;width:90pt;height:80.4pt;z-index:251661312;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:0;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-width-relative:margin;mso-height-relative:margin;v-text-anchor:top",
>   Alternate = "Title: circle", OptionalString = "_x0000_s1026",
>   FillColor = "#4472c4 [3204]", StrokeColor = "white [3212]",
>   StrokeWeight = "1pt" };

Comment: Try creating two documents with only an oval, one with one color, the second with the other color. Open the first in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool then choose to compare with the second. You should get code that shows how to change the one to the other - compare this to what you're doing and see if you can find the difference. If you expect anyone here to help you in more detail, you need to provide repro steps and more complete code (see [mcve]).

Comment: @CindyMeister Cindy, thank you.  I apologize for the short explanation. I didn't download the Tool until you suggested it and am glad I did.  I did as you said and created two simple documents with just a Header to replace and the oval (no tables).  Used output from the Tool to get new Hex code for FillColor.  I have added more above.  Still not getting result.  Do I need to .Append to the Oval.FillColor property instead of trying to directly set it?  Do I need to Save the WordProcessingDocument separately for a property as opposed to the text that is updated?

Comment: The tool should also show you the *code* required to create the one document from the other. Does that show you anything useful? (Note that I don't know the answer - I'd have to go through these steps, myself, and currently I don't have a lot of time for that kind of research...)

Comment: @CindyMeister Yes, the tool was the answer and I can't thank you enough.  I had just started using openxml and the tool helped me understand, among many other things, how much nesting there is in the xml.  It showed me that the Oval.FillColor could be different in 2 docx and the color would still be the same.  I am going to put the answer below. Thanks again.  I will look for your name when searching.

Answer (score 1):

Note:  I am using a docx template (copied to become newpath in using statement below) stored on my server.  In order to access the shape you want to change, in this case my oval, I had to set the Title for the shape.  Do this by right click on shape in docx... 
Format Shape/Layout & Properties/Alt Text/Title  and set the Title value (mine is circle)

The `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Oval` `FillColor` property wasn't what sets the color of my oval.  The Open XML Productivity Tool helped me find where the color is actually set.  In my actual docx, the `ShapeProperties` I needed is 17 levels down the xml hierarchy.  By taking Cindy's advice and creating a simple docx with just the oval and one other paragraph I was able to determine what value I needed to set.

The `ShapeProperties` are nested within an `Anchor` where the `Anchor`'s `DocProperties` has a `Title`, which in my case I am looking for "circle", the Title I set in the docx.

```
 using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(newpath, true))
            {
          var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
          var anchor = body.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing.Anchor>();
                foreach (var anc in anchor)
                {
                    var docProperties = anc.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing.DocProperties>().Where(tp => tp.Title != null);
                    foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing.DocProperties docProp in docProperties)
                    {
                        if (docProp.Title.Value == "circle")
                        {
                            var shapes = anc.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.Word.DrawingShape.WordprocessingShape>();
                            foreach (var sh in shapes)
                            {
                                foreach (var sp in sh.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.Word.DrawingShape.ShapeProperties>())
                                {
                                    foreach (var fill in sp.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.SolidFill>())
                                    {
                                        // deleting SchemeColor if already set up in the solidfill
                                        if (fill.SchemeColor != null) { fill.SchemeColor.Remove(); }
                                        // m.QLA.CircleColorHex is simply a string representing the color in 6 char Hex - this does not use the # before, so a value is like "FFFFFF" 
                                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.RgbColorModelHex rgb = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = m.QLA.CircleColorHex };
                                        fill.Append(rgb);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```